# AngularJS fails to load Bing Maps

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I'm using AngularJS to display Bing Maps, but the error says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of null".  Please take a look below.

In my Razor view file has the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/Site.js"></script>
----
----
--
<div ng-app="myDisplayItems">
    <div ng-controller="myDisplayItemsController">
        <div id="myMap"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my JavaScript file has:

```
var displayItems = angular.module("myDisplayItems", []);
displayItems.controller("myDisplayItemsController", function myDisplayItemsController($scope) {
    showMap();
});

function showMap() {         
    var key = "######";

    var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {
        credentials: key,
        zoom: 3
    });
}
```

**Update:**

```
var displayItems = angular.module("myDisplayItems", []);
displayItems.controller("myDisplayItemsController", function myDisplayItemsController($scope) {
   $scope.map = null;
   $scope.init = function () {
         $scope.map = showMap();
   };

   angular.element(document).ready(function () {
         $scope.init();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this error occurs since Bing Maps library is *not yet ready* once the map is initialized.

No error occurs, is `showMap` function is invoked after some delay (assuming Bing Maps library has been loaded by that moment), for example like this:

```
$timeout(function() { $scope.initMap()}, 2000);
```

But i would propose the following solution:

Register the function that needs to be triggered once Bing Maps library is ready, like this:

```
Microsoft.Maps.CallbackOnLoad = "initMap";
```

and declare `initMap` a *global* function:

```
$window.showMap = function () {
   //...
}
```

Demo

```js
angular.module('mapApp', []);
    angular
        .module('mapApp')
        .controller('MapController', MapController);

    function MapController($scope, $window) {

        $window.initMap = function () {
            let map = new window.Microsoft.Maps.Map(
                document.getElementById('myMap'), {
                    credentials: 'AjwUEXFZA8SMyy8CaJj59vJKVDoWohNXVFz_uGyHlT8N40Jgr-zrhvcxbTNRyDqn'
                });
            map.setView({
                zoom: 6,
                center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(52.406978607177734, -1.5077600479125977)
            });
        }

        Microsoft.Maps.CallbackOnLoad = "initMap";
    }
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>

<div ng-app="mapApp" ng-controller="MapController">
    <div id="myMap" style="width:600px;height:400px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding.  It's going to take me a while to figure out what you meant because I'm still learning JavaScript, Angular, Bing Maps and MVC concepts.

Comment: Following your suggestion, i am able to display the map.  Next phase will use $http call to get longitude and latitude from MS SQL Server database.